# Git for OpenBSD on a DEC VAX?

Tags: git, compilation, bsd, openbsd, vax

I am trying to find a binary install of Git for OpenBSD v5.2 running on a DEC VaxStation 4000 Model 90? My particular machine has a staggering 32 megs of RAM but does run GCC version 2.9.5 and Perl 5 version 12 so I suspect I probably can run Git.

Is anybody aware of a Git binary (any version) for the VAX architecture or should I try to compile from source? There is no binary for Git on the OpenBSD packages repository.

Comment: there is most probably no binary, compiling it yourself is your best option :)

Answer (score 0):

Don’t compile it from source yourself but try using the ports tree. The unavailability of a ready-made binary package does not mean compiling from a port won’t work, only that nobody made and published it.

But talk to e.g. Miod beforehand, maybe they have tried and failed. Many modern software won’t build with GCC 2.95 or even 3.4.6 any more ☹